# JUnit4 and JUnit5 tests not running in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit, junit4, junit5

I am trying to use JUnit4 and JUnit5 tests in the same project in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.5. Until now, all tests were based on JUnit4. I added the `jupiter`, `platform` and `vintage` dependencies to my pom.xml (including the `junit-platform-surefire-provider` and `junit-vintage-engine` for the surefire plugin). **Now, neither my example test for JUnit4 nor the one for JUnit 5 are executed.**

Instead, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.getDefaultClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry.loadTestEngines(ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry.java:30)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.createListeners(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Process finished with exit code 1
Empty test suite.
```

I tried to follow the advice from the [JUnit 5 User Guide](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) as closely as possible but I probably missed something. **How can I get both tests to run properly?** (and all my existing tests, of course)

### JUnit 4 Test Class

```
package com.glaed.util;

import org.junit.Test;

public class JUnit4Test {

  @Test
  public void helloJUnit4Test() {
    System.out.println("Hello JUnit4!");
  }

}
```

### JUnit 5 Test Class

```
package com.glaed.util;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class JUnit5Test {

  @Test
  void helloJU5test() {
    System.out.println("Hello JUnit5!");
  }
}
```

### pom.xml (relevant parts)

```
    <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*WebappTest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0-M5</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.0.0-M5</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>4.12.0-M5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <!-- JUNIT5 & JUPITER -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-M5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-M5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>4.12.0-M5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUnit 4 -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: get this exact same error with just maven - but then I saw you're controlling the maven surefire plugin dependencies, otherwise - like my issue - it pulls in an older version of JUnit5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the following version of `junit-jupiter-api` :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId> 
  <version>5.0.0-M4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And also use on version `5.0.0-M4` for all `junit-jupiter` dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! That has to do with IntelliJ only supporting a specific JUnit5 milestone for now, right?

Comment: Right. See details at http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea

Comment: Note: This workaround for Gradle (adding testRuntime dependencies) does not work for Android projects as the Gradle Android plugin does not support the testRuntime keyword

Answer (score 0):

junit-jupiter for JUnit 5 and junit-vintage for older versions, 
if you are using junit 5 only, only junit-jupiter will be enough, 
and if you have already implemented JUnit 4 ore any older versions implementations you have to use both the junit-jupiter and junit-vintage dependencies.

**Note**
JUnit 5’s architecture also supports running multiple test engines simultaneously: you can run the JUnit Vintage test engine with virtually any other test engine that is compatible with JUnit 5.